# Upgrade 12c client to 19c client

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-19c

Does Oracle 19c client upgrade 12c client if installed or does 12c client have to be uninstalled prior to 19c installation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as in-place upgrade from 12c to 19c.

You will need to install the 19c client to a new location anyway.

The old client can be removed or left as is.